# Java Beginner need advice? if ( amount == String)?

Tags: java

I'm practicing with some simple tasks in java bank account and need advice for code block , how to write this?
Here is example, how to put in Else if block amount == String if user put string or some letter instead of number to print "please enter a number" for example, many thx

```
            case 2:
            int amount = 0;
            System.out.println("Amount to withdraw:");
            amount = in.nextInt();
            if(amount <= 0)
            {
                System.err.println("you cannot withdraw negative amount!");
            }
            else if(amount > balans)
            {
                System.err.println("Not enough money on account!");
            }
            else if(...) // Here l need that
            {
                System.err.println("please enter a number instead of letters");
            }
            else
            {
                balans-=amount;
                System.out.println("You have successfully withdrawn " + amount + " €");
            }
```

Comment: Use regex instead to check alphabets.

Comment: you can fine lot of stuff in google eg. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

Comment: @Shriram regex is not needed here since `Scanner` (and based on `nextInt()` I suspect that `in` is instance of `Scanner`) provides its own methods checking for type of value provided by user like `hasNextInt`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply check type of value provided by user before storing it in `amount`. You can use `in.hasNextInt` for that. If it is not `Integer` ask user to wire proper value again.

You could try with something like

```
System.out.print("write Integer: ");
while(!in.hasNextInt()){      //used didn't provide valid value
    String value = in.next(); //lets consume it so Scanner can read and test next value
    System.out.println(value +" is not considered valid Integer.");
    System.our.print("please try again: ");
}
//here we are sure that user provided proper integer
amount = in.nextInt();

//and now we can proceed with rest of code
if(amount <= 0){
   ...
}
```

You can also add counter of tries and user will not provide proper value in lets say 3 tries exit the program.

Comment: @downvoter I am not saying that my answer is perfect, so if you found some problem with it I would be grateful if you inform me about it so I could correct it.

Comment: yea mate this is nice and works, thx . But what if l don't wont to ask him "write integer"  ? 
only if he put String instead of int , System.out.println("please enter a number instead of letters");
is that possible?

Comment: @Cleverson I didn't say that you need to use precisely messages from my answer, you can organize them as you want. I only tried to show you that you could use `hasNextInt` to determine that user didn't provide valid number (which  I believe was your main problem). Oh, and not so obvious part of my answer is that we need to *consume* invalid value stored by scanner (I am doing it with `next()`). Otherwise Scanner would be testing with `hasNextInt` same value.

Answer (score 1):

If the user enters something that is not a number, then this line:

```
  amount = in.nextInt();
```

will throw an exception (`InputMismatchException`).  There are two options:

- Enclose the call (and the following tests) in a `try` block, and `catch` the exception.  You can print your "this isn't a number" message in the catch block.
- Call `in.hasNextInt()` before `nextInt` to see if the `nextInt()` call will succeed.

---

By the way, the message "please enter a number instead of letters" would confuse a real user of a real ATM if he/she entered "1.00" or "$1".  They would likely say "I DID enter a number.  Stoopid machine!"

You need to think carefully about the wording of messages that are supposed to be understood by non-IT folk.

(Actually, anyone really.  It is just that IT folks are used to interpolating obscure or badly phrased error messages ... because they see a lot of them.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple regex.

```
    String regex = "\\d+";
    String test = "ss";

    if(!test.matches(regex))
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter integers.");
    }
```

output = Please enter integers.

Comment: Scanner.hasNextInt() is simpler AND it should deal with the case where the number entered is too large.  (Your regex won't do that.)

Comment: Cleverson, if you don't need to large numbers, this will help you. But Stephen is right.